# How can I get the ToolTip on the Form that contains a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a class, `Validator`, which validates fields in all the Forms of a project.
I want to refer (from the function) the ToolTip on the form that contains the control which is being validated. This control is the function argument.

```
public static Boolean ValidateText(object sender)
{
     //Error CS0039
     ToolTip ttHelp = (sender as TextBox).FindForm().Controls["myToolTip"] as ToolTip;

     if((sender as TextBox).Text == "") {
         ttHelp.SetToolTIp(someControl,someMessage);
     }
    // [...]
}
```

> Error CS0039  Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: Please elaborate. 1) Do you have multiple Forms opened when you call this method? 2) Where do you call this method? From a Form? If yes, then you can pass it's ToolTip as a second parameter.  Like: `public static Boolean ValidateText(object sender, ToolTip ttHelp) { .. }`.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple forms opened when I call this methos. I have a class Validator which validate fields in all the forms. My project is almost done and if I pass a second parameter to the function I have to modify its call everywhere - a lot of work to do, but if I could refere the tooltip from function is enough to modify the function. Thanks a lot for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip) is not a Control, it's a [Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component), so you won't find it in a Form's Controls collection.
It's instead part of the **`System.ComponentModel.IContainer components`** private Field, usually defined in the Form's Designer section of the partial class.

To find the ToolTip of a control, you can use the [ToolTip.GetToolTip([Control])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.gettooltip) method, then verify whether the string returned is empty.

If you can access the Form's `components` Field - i.e., the `ValidateText()` method is called from the Form that contains the Control to validate - you can pass the components container to the method:

► If the Form has no Components, `container` (in both methods) will be `null`.
► If the Form has no ToolTip components, `var toolTip` will be `null`.

→ Keeping `object sender`, then casting to Control, since here you want to access only common Properties, like `Text`, which belong to the common Control class. You don't need to know `sender`'s type: [Control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,68) is the base type of all controls and exposes all the common properties.

```
bool result = ValidateText(this.someControl, this.components);
// [...]

public static bool ValidateText(object sender, IContainer container)
{
    if (container == null) {
        /* no components, decide what to do */
        // [...] 
    }

    var ctrl = sender as Control;
    var toolTip = container.Components.OfType<ToolTip>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(tt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tt.GetToolTip(ctrl)));

    if (toolTip != null) {
        string tooltipText = toolTip.GetToolTip(ctrl);
        // [...]
        if (ctrl.Text == "") { }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise, you can access the components collection via reflection, in case the Control instance passed to the `ValidateText()` method may have an undetermined origin.

With `[form].GetType().GetField("components").GetValue([form]) as IContainer` we can access the `components` Field value then continue as before.

→ Here, `sender` is of type Control already, since this is the real *nature* of `sender`.

→ `ValidateText([Control])` overloads the previous method. You can call `ValidateText(sender, container)` when you have assigned a value to `container`.

```
bool result = ValidateText(someControl); 
// [...]


using System.Reflection;

public static bool ValidateText(Control sender)
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField;
    Form form = sender.FindForm();

    var container = form.GetType().GetField("components", flags).GetValue(form) as IContainer;
    if (container == null) {
        /* no components, decide what to do */
        // [...] 
    }

    // You can call ValidateText(sender, container) or continue
    var toolTip = container.Components.OfType<ToolTip>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(tt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tt.GetToolTip(sender)));

    if (toolTip != null) {
        string tooltipText = toolTip.GetToolTip(sender);
        // [...]
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot, but form.GetType().GetField("components", flags) is null. I let public the components field in the form. To pass a second parameter is too much work to do - modify all the function calls in project.

Comment: Don't set the `components` field public. If `form.GetType().GetField().GetValue()` returns `null`, then the Form has no components (thus the `components` Field has never been assigned a value) or you didn't use the code presented here as it is. Plus, the first method overloads the second. You don't need to change anything in your code. You can call one or the other or make the second (`ValidateText(Control sender)`) call the first. As you like.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Jimi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971054/10216583) to understand why your code doesn't work.

**Plus** your `Validator` class can be refactored as follows to *validate* the TextBox controls in different ways. A single control, group of controls hosted by a Form or other container, and the controls of the [OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1).

Also The [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netcore-3.1) component is recommended for tasks as such. The `Validator` class provides both, the [ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=netcore-3.1) and [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netcore-3.1) services. Note that, the base class of the target controls is the [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase?view=netcore-3.1) class, so you can validate any control derives from this base class such as; TextBox, RichTextBox, ToolStripTextBox...etc.

Please read the explanatory comments of each member.

```cs
internal sealed class Validator 
{
    private static Validator Current;
    //Each Form has its own ToolTip...
    private readonly Dictionary<Form, ToolTip> ToolTips;
    private readonly ErrorProvider ErrPro;

    private Validator()
    {
        ToolTips = new Dictionary<Form, ToolTip>();
        ErrPro = new ErrorProvider();
    }

    static Validator() => Current = new Validator();

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable/disable the ToolTip service.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ToolTipEnabled { get; set; } = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable/disable the ErrorProvider service.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ErrorProviderEnabled { get; set; } = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set/get the ToolTip/ErrorProvider message.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Message { get; set; } = "Hello World";

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate a single TextBox or RichTextBox control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="txt">TextBox/RichTextBox..etc.</param>
    public static void Validate(TextBoxBase txt)
    {
        if (txt is null) return;
        var f = txt.FindForm();
        if (f is null) return;

        //Add a Form into the Dictionary and create a new ToolTip for it.
        if (!Current.ToolTips.ContainsKey(f))
        {
            Current.ToolTips.Add(f, new ToolTip());
            Current.ToolTips[f].ShowAlways = true; //Optional...

            //Cleanup. Remove the closed Forms and dispose the related disposables.
            f.HandleDestroyed += (s, e) =>
            {
                Current.ToolTips[f].Dispose();
                Current.ToolTips.Remove(f);
                if (Current.ToolTips.Count() == 0) Current.ErrPro.Dispose();
            };
        }

        if (txt.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            if (ToolTipEnabled)
                Current.ToolTips[f].SetToolTip(txt, Message);

            if (ErroProviderEnabled)
                Current.ErrPro.SetError(txt, Message);
        }
        else
        {
            Current.ToolTips[f].SetToolTip(txt, null);
            Current.ErrPro.SetError(txt, null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An overload that takes a container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">Form/Panel/GroupBox...etc</param>
    public static void Validate(Control container)
    {
        if (container is null) return;

        foreach (var c in GetAllControls<TextBoxBase>(container))
            Validate(c);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the open Forms.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ValidateOpenForms()
    {
        foreach (var f in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>())
            Validate(f);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear and remove the messages explicitly.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Clear()
    {
        Current.ToolTips.Values.ToList().ForEach(x => x.RemoveAll());
        Current.ErrPro.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A recursive function to get the controls from a given container.
    /// </summary>
    private static IEnumerable<T> GetAllControls<T>(Control container)
    {
        var controls = container.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControls<T>(ctrl)).Concat(controls.OfType<T>());
    }
}
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```cs
void TheCaller()
{
    //Set the desired properties.
    Validator.Message = "Hello World!";
    Validator.ErrorProviderEnabled = true;

    //Validate a single control.
    Validator.Validate(textBox1);

    //Or the controls of the current Form.
    Validator.Validate(this);

    //Or all the open Forms.
    Validator.ValidateOpenForms();            
}
```